# Pyqt bind function to dinamically generated push buttons

Tags: qt, python-2.7, lambda, pyqt4, dynamically-generated

Using the PyQT library I am currently having issues with binding a function to the dinamically generated pushbuttons resulting from a loop.

So far I have managed to generate the buttons and bind a function to them with the lambda command. The problem is that since I need every single button to open a different file I find myself in an odd situation as all the button do open the same one. The last value assigned to the variable.

Any idea on how to fix the situation? As a last note, sorry in case of stupid mistakes. I am new to OOP and PyQT.

```
def searchTheStuff(self):
        found = 0
        data = MainWindow.intermediateCall()
        f1 = open('Path.txt', 'r')
        path = f1.read()
        f1.close()
        Yinc = 25
        Y = 40
        X = 20
        results = 0
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
            for name in files:
                if name.endswith('.txt'):
                    fullpath = os.path.join(path, name)
                    mail = open_close(fullpath)
                    if mail.find(data) != -1 and results<3:
                        found = 1
                        self.buttons.append(QtGui.QPushButton(self))
                        print fullpath
                        command = lambda : webbrowser.open()
                        self.buttons[-1].clicked.connect(command)
                        self.buttons[-1].setText(_translate("self", name, None))
                        self.buttons[-1].setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(X, Y, 220, 20))
                        results = results+1
                        if results == 33:
                            X = 260
                            Y = 15
                        Y = Y + Yinc
        if found == 0:
            self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 321, 21))
            self.label.setText(_translate("self", "No templates have been found:", None))
```

Comment: `lambda path=fullpath: webbrowser.open(path)`.

Comment: That returns   File "C:\Python27\lib\webbrowser.py", line 61, in open
    if browser.open(url, new, autoraise):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\webbrowser.py", line 543, in open
    os.startfile(url)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found

Comment: Sorry, yes - annoyingly, the clicked signal always sends its checked state as the first parameter, so you need `lambda checked, path=fullpath: webbrowser.open(path)`.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much, it works now. Love you :D